# user_save doesn't do anything?

Tags: php, drupal, module

So I'm trying to make a form that creates a user and everything works... except the part that actually saves the user to the database...

The thing about it is that the user_save function isn't even returning a false or null value. It is just stopping the script altogether. I even tried echoing some values after it and they are inaccessible.

After hours of echoing out values, I have narrowed it down to the `execute()` method of the query object.

Here is the code:

```
$account = array(
    'name' => $user_email,
    'pass' => $user_password,
    'mail' => $uer_email,
    'theme' => '',
    'signature' => '',
    'signature_format' => NULL,
    'created' => 0,
    'access' => 0,
    'login' => 0,
    'status' => 1,
    'timezone' => NULL,
    'language' => '',
    'picture' => 0,
    'init' => 'email address',
    'data' => NULL
);

if (user_save(NULL, $account)) {
    user_authenticate($user_email, $user_password);
} else {
    echo "Something looks broken.";
}
```

I have checked the Apache / PHP / MySQL logs and there are absolutely no notable errors. I thought that there might be a problem with how my data is set up in the array. Before this, I defined only the fields that HAD to be defined but it made no difference.

What do you think is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
'init' => 'email address',
```

should be:

```
'init' => $uer_email,
```

The following code is all you need to create a new user, try starting from this and then adding the other values that you need.

```
$account = array(
  'name' => $user_email,
  'pass' => $user_password,
  'mail' => $user_email,
  'status' => 1,
  'init' => $user_email
);
user_save(null, $account);
```